# wait for API request to complete in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I know how to wait for requests sent by application under test - using interception and alias and wait for this alias.

But how to wait for request issued by `cy.request()`?

I can assign an alias to it:

```
cy.request('POST', '/Sessions', USER_CREDENTIALS_ADMIN).as('login').then(response => {
    ....
});
cy.wait('@login');
```

But then I have error:

```
cy.wait() only accepts aliases for routes. The alias: login did not match a route.
```

Without `cy.wait('@login');` it does what is expected (logins user).

Comment: The simple answer, as best as I know it, is that you can't. Is there a reason you want to wait on this call? Because of how it operates in the Cypress command chain, Cypress will automatically wait for the request to complete before moving on. Are you looking to re-use some of the code used in your `cy.request()`?

Comment: @agoff sometimes logging request takes too much time and when I want to visit main page there is login dialog shown. I mean application starts to execute before login request completes.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress automatically waits for a `cy.request()` to complete.

Using [deelay.me](https://deelay.me/) to fake a slow request

```js
it('Cypress waits for request to complete', () => {
  
  // delay request response by 3 seconds
  cy.request('https://deelay.me/3000/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(() => console.log('Request complete'))

  cy.visit('http://example.com', {
    onBeforeLoad: () => console.log('Before visit')
  })
})
```

Logs:

- Request complete  ✅
- Before visit

---

However, if I have some asynchronous processing on the result of the request, it does not wait

```js
it('Cypress waits for request to complete', () => {
  
  cy.request('https://deelay.me/3000/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => console.log('Timeout complete'), 2000)
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Request complete'))

  cy.visit('http://example.com', {
    onBeforeLoad: () => console.log('Before visit')
  })
})
```

Logs:

- Request complete
- Before visit
- Timeout complete  ❌

---

It can be fixed by wrapping in a Promise, since Cypress automatically waits for a Promise

```js
it('Cypress waits for request to complete', () => {
  
  cy.request('https://deelay.me/3000/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(() => {
      return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
          console.log('Timeout complete')
          resolve()
        }, 2000)
      })
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Request complete'))

  cy.visit('http://example.com', {
    onBeforeLoad: () => console.log('Before visit')
  })
})
```

Logs:

- Timeout complete   ✅
- Request complete
- Before visit

Comment: I can't use remote services like delay.me.

Comment: You don't have to - the code above is to illustrate that your assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve something like this would be to add it as a custom command, and have that command be chainable.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('requestSessions', () => {
  return cy.request(...).then((res) => {...});
});
```

If you're declaring your custom commands in the Cypress namespace, you can leave off a return type.

```js
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      requestSessions();
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to simply use the function in a Cypress chain and have Cypress wait for the command to finish before continuing.

```js
cy.requestSessions()
  .visit('/foo');
```